# Inno-Setup: SetupIconFile: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to create the installation **Setup.exe** file using **Inno-Setup** as follow:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Muwassa
AppVersion=1.0
AppVerName=Muwassa 1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\Muwassa
DefaultGroupName=Muwassa
Compression=zip
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=.
SetupIconFile={app}\muwassa.ico
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\muwassa.ico
AllowCancelDuringInstall=no
DisableDirPage =yes
AppContact=info@DevSuda.com
AppPublisher=DevSuda Ltd.
SetupLogging=yes

[Files]
Source: "Muwassa.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "README.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme
Source: "*.*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: replacesameversion recursesubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Muwassa"; Filename: "{app}\Muwassa.exe"
Name: "{group}\Uninstall"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: {commondesktop}\Muwassa; Filename: {app}\Muwassa.exe; WorkingDir: {app}; IconFilename: {app}\muwassa.ico; Comment: "Muwassa"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\Muwassa.exe"
```

But at line 10:

```
SetupIconFile={app}\muwassa.ico
```

This error message comes up:

> Line 10:
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.

Even though I am using a similar syntax for uninstallation icon:

```
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\muwassa.ico
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{app}` constant contains

> The application directory, which the user selects on the Select
>   Destination Location page of the wizard.

[Documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts)

So the value is set during *run time*. The setup's icon file needs to be known during *compile time*. That's why the file can't be found.

Comment: It's not about the `{app}` only. Any constant is known at run time only. For this reason, the constants are not even resolved in `SetupIconFile` directive as it is used on compile time only.